# Javascript array doesn't notice new images in folder

Tags: php, javascript, lightbox, slideshow

Yesterday I got a question about a slideshow with lightbox fixed on stackoverflow but now I came to another problem.. I create an Javascript array trough php and in JS I make the slideshow work + lightbox work. Now when I add a new image to the images folder it does include it in the src"" attribute but does not show the image and instead shows the error picture when an image doesn't work (couldn't include an image because I don't have enough rep if you would like the image of the problem, I can send it)

This is the php code part:

```
//This function gets the file names of all images in the current directory
//and ouputs them as a JavaScript array
function returnimages($dirname   ="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/slidepluslight/slideshows/minpunten/images/") {
$pattern="(\.jpg$)|(\.png$)|(\.jpeg$)|(\.gif$)"; //valid image extensions
$files = array();
$curimage=0;
if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
if(eregi($pattern, $file)){ //if this file is a valid image
//Output it as a JavaScript array element
print_r ('galleryarray['.$curimage.']="'.$file .'";');
$curimage++;
}
}

closedir($handle);
}
return($files);
}

print 'var galleryarray=new Array();'; //Define array in JavaScript
returnimages() //Output the array elements containing the image file names

?>
```

And this is the Javascript code that makes the slideshow + lightbox work.

```
var curimg=0;

function rotateimages(){
document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "images/"+galleryarray[curimg]);
curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0;
}

window.onload = function(){
setInterval("rotateimages()", 500);
}

window.onload = function(){
setInterval("rotateimages()", 2500);
document.getElementById("slideshow").onclick = function () {
var imageSrc = document.getElementById("slideshow").src;
document.getElementById("lightImg").setAttribute("src", imageSrc);
document.getElementById('lightbox').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('fade').style.display = 'block';
}
}
```

It all runs fine but when I add a new image to the images folder it doesn't show it..

Regards Koen.

UPDATE, everything worked but we tried to do it dynamically but now the src"" gives me undefined.. Does somebody see where I code it wrong?

The php part:

```
 function returnimages($relPath = "/slidepluslight/slideshows/minpunten/images/") {
 $dirname = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] + $relPath;
 $files = array();
 $curimage = 0;
 if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
 while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
 if (preg_match('/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/', $file)){ //if this file is a valid image
 //Output it as a JavaScript array element
 print_r ('galleryarray['.$curimage.']="'. $relPath + $file .'";');
 $curimage++;
 }
 } 

 closedir($handle);
 }
 return($files);
 }

 print 'var galleryarray=new Array();'; //Define array in JavaScript
 returnimages() //Output the array elements containing the image file names
```

And the Javascript part:

```
var curimg=0;

function rotateimages(){
document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", galleryarray[curimg]);
curimg=(curimg<galleryarray.length-1)? curimg+1 : 0;
}
```

Kinds regards,

Koen.

Comment: I found your explanation a little confusing. Are you saying that when you refresh the page in the browser and then "View Source" the new image file names _do_ appear in the array in the (generated) JS, but the new images don't load and older images do load?

Comment: Note - `eregi()` is deprecated. You should use `preg_match()` instead:  `if (preg_match('/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/', $file))`

Comment: @nnnnnn Yes, that's the problem. When I view the source code in Chrome it does show src"images/keuken1.jpg" But where you should see the image I get an error image.

Comment: Is it something to do with permissions on the individual new image files, that they aren't accessible via http request?

Comment: @Michael, thanks for noticing I changed that. But unfortunately it doesn't change the problem..

Comment: @KoenVoogd That's what it was a comment and not an answer. :)

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't know, I am pretty new to both Javascript and php. But I am at the moment running the code on my localhost, so there's no http request involved I think?

Comment: Change this line
`document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "images/"+galleryarray[curimg]);` to `document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "/slidepluslight/slideshows/minpunten/images/"+galleryarray[curimg]);`.  I'd like to know what happens after that change.

Comment: @Michael, I know ^^ Thanks for the comment :)

Comment: @Will, this module is for a client of mine and I am going to implement it in Joomla making a module of it. The part in the php where it gets the images should later be done automatically with a function and the Javascript part should copy the path to the folder. When I will do that, will it than add the full path that the PHP code gives me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you were having trouble is you weren't properly refering to the location of the images.  <strike>I'll find some links to have you look it in a min.</strike>

If you change

```
document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "images/"+galleryarray[curimg]);
```

to

```
document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "/slidepluslight/slideshows/minpunten/images/"+galleryarray[curimg]);
```

the browser will know to look in the `/slidepluslight/slideshows/minpunten/images` directory for the images.

---

The remander of this answer applies to the dynamic URL issue so this solution could be used in other applications.

As far as making the links to the images dynamic it seems to me like it needs to be addressed in the `returnimages` function.

Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to get the root directory of website.  Here that is `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` and then have the rest specified as a parameter to `returnimages`.

```
function returnimages($relPath = "/slidepluslight/slideshows/minpunten/images/") {
    $dirName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $relPath;
    ...
    /* Where you are outputting the JS array */
    print_r ('galleryarray['.$curimage.']="'. $relPath + $file .'";');
    ....
}
```

Comment: This was the part that worked! I can't upvote, to low rep, sorry :) But Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I'm editing my answer to solve the second issue you mentioned in the comments.  I'll have something up in a few moments.

Comment: Okay, I've got all day! Thanks for your time :)

Comment: And should I add this to the first or last returnimages?

Comment: The PHP one.  Also change this line in the JS one `document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", "images/"+galleryarray[curimg]);` to `document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", galleryarray[curimg]);` since we will be using php to tell javascript exactly where the files are we don't need to have JS assume anything anymore.

Comment: Hmm, I know receive img"undefined"

Comment: I now changed the php to this: 
    function returnimages($relPath =   "/slidepluslight/slideshows/minpunten/images/") {
    $dirname = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] + $relPath;
    $files = array();
    $curimage=0;
    if($handle = opendir($dirname)) {
    while(false !== ($file = readdir($handle))){
    if (preg_match('/\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$/', $file)){ //if this file   is a valid image
    //Output it as a JavaScript array element
    printf('galleryarray[%d]="%s";', $curimage, $relPath + $file);
    $curimage++;
    }
    }

Comment: Drat, it's tough to work on when I can't really work on it. Is the JS array being output correctly?

Comment: I changed it as you explained: document.getElementById("slideshow").setAttribute("src", galleryarray[curimg]);

Comment: Please view-source of where the JS array is created and show me that.

Comment: No, do a view-source from your browser.

Comment: Well, in my browser it only tell me src"undefined" and in Chrome at scripts i find: var galleryarray=new Array();

Comment: Okay, perhaps I did my `printf` wrong please look back at my answer.  Specifically the `print_r` statement.  Replace the `printf` with the code in my updated answer.

Comment: Sorry `$relpath` needs to be `$relPath`.  I just noticed it and changed it on my answer (`print_r` statement).

Comment: Hehe, true. But I already noticed that myself when walking trough the code but it didn't help :(

Comment: I apologize for needing all of these comments to debug what is going on here.  I feel like a dolt.  Anyway since all we're seeing in the script is `var galleryarray=new Array();` it is clear that for whatever reason the `print_r` statement isn't being executed.  Since the `preg_match` seems fine I suspect somehow `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` isn't giving you `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs` as I would expect.  

Perhaps it would be best to change your solution back to using the static path since that was working and open another question focusing on getting the URLs to be dynamic.

Comment: No problem for the comments, I just didn't have enough reputation yet to open a chat. Well I don't really understand why it isn't working either.. But the first solution worked so I changed it to that one again. I now just go and start turning it into a module and when I come to a problem I'll find my answer to the dynamic URL's. Thanks for your help, I'm glad you took time for me! Regards, Koen.

Comment: Can't chat, need 20 rep there also.. Hmm and now I have 20 rep and I still can't talk there lol..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9967/discussion-between-koen-voogd-and-will)